# Run JUnit Tests of Java SE library on Android emulator or device

Tags: java, android, maven, junit

I have a simple library which compiles and runs on Java SE and builds with Maven. The test classes are JUnit test cases (currently 4.x, no problem to downgrade to 3.x).

The library can be used in Android, but has no dependencies on `android.*`.
It is absolutely necessary to run the JUnit tests on an emulator or Android device, since there are some subtle differences in the JDK (Java SE and Android/Harmony).

**I don't want to copy the test cases** to an Hello-Testing Android project, but reuse the existing classes.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the tests on the android emulator you need to create a Test Project (this can only use JUnit 3), that is depending on a normal Android Project.

I would suggest you add a Test-suit to your library tests containing calls to all tests of your library. Create a simple Hello Word Android Project. Create a Android Test Project for this Project. Then you can call the new created test-suit from your Android Test Project and you do not need to copy any test cases. All you do is building some Wrapper Projects.

Comment: Sounds good! Do you have a suggestion how to provide the test.jar for the Wrapper project? I found `mvn jar:test-jar`. Is there a standard way?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have not done this before. I don't know the best practice way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not the optimum solution, but I managed to test the library running in Android (Simulator or real device). You can find it on [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb/tree/master/src/test/android).

```
public class DavidWebbAndroidTests extends TestSuite {
    public static Test suite () {
        return new TestSuiteBuilder(DavidWebbAndroidTests.class)
            .includeAllPackagesUnderHere()
            .build();
    }
}
```

The caveat is that I have to extend all tests so that they are present on Android.

Hopefully someone will find a better solution, but at least it works.